# Rule for getting banned from flagging

Tags: support, flagging

I have been banned from flagging because 3 of my flags (not consecutive) were declined. And it says '**You are currently banned from flagging**'. I want to know:

> 1 How many wrong flags do result in a ban?

> 2 Will I be ever again be able raise flags? If yes when?

Comment: The rules are [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/177145), it's not an absolute number of declined flags, it's proportional. The flag ban lasts one week maximum.

Comment: Flag hellban used to be forever...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The criteria for flag-bans are listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/177145). The short summary is

- Only post flags are considered, not comment flags.
- Flag bans last between one day and one week, they are now never permanent (as they used to be).
- If one had at least ten post flags handled during the last seven days (it doesn't matter when the flags were cast), and

  - at least 10% of those flags were declined, one is **warned** when flagging,
  - at least 25% of those flags were declined, one is temporarily **banned** from flagging.
- If fewer than 10 flags were handled during the last seven days, one is warned if the previous flag was declined, regardless of how the other flags were judged. Unless the flag in question is the tenth being handled in the seven day period, a decline cannot cause a flag ban.